# How come a rape is considered a damage but not a crime in Judaism?

Tags: rambam, sexuality, reward-punishment

In our Western (Goyish) culture, rape constitutes a serious criminal offense (up to 15 years inside), that is probably based on a Pshat of [Deu 22, 26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.22.26?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he):

> וְלַנַּעֲרָה לֹא־תַעֲשֶׂה דָבָר אֵין לַנַּעֲרָה חֵטְא מָוֶת כִּי
>   כַּאֲשֶׁר יָקוּם אִישׁ עַל־רֵעֵהוּ וּרְצָחוֹ נֶפֶשׁ כֵּן הַדָּבָר הַזֶּה׃
>
> for as when a man riseth against his neighbor, and slayeth him, even so, is this matter [a rape of an engaged girl]."

Rashi: "כִּי אֲנוּסָה הִיא וּבְחָזְקָה עָמַד עָלֶיהָ, כְּאָדָם הָעוֹמֵד עַל חֲבֵרוֹ לְהָרְגוֹ. "

How come that the Torah compares rape to a murder, but in the Halacha, there's no punishment for this crime?

Comment: Where do we ever see lashes given when there is already a fine? (There is indeed one specific exception, but that just proves the rule, as they say.)

Comment: Correct, but where do we find getting away with a fine for a Lav?

Comment: Every time you damage someone. Suppose I cut off your arm.

Comment: You seem to be conflating the crime of lo tihyeh kdesha, with the crime of rape. Which one do you think ought to warrant malkut?

Comment: I understood from Rambam, that any relations outside the wedlock is considered by Rambam Beilas Znus and therefore ought to warrant malkut. A rape is such relations.

Comment: Again, if you want a user to see your comments, make sure to use a @. Ok. If you think that the malkut should be for the beilat zenut, then the rape element is a total non sequitur that just confuses the question.

Comment: Unclear if the question is malkut for rape, or for lo tihye kdesha.

Comment: Agree with @mevaqesh. The Rambam is discussing a different case than the one cited in Deuteronomy 22.

Comment: For starters, you appear to contradict yourself by *repeatedly* saying that there is no criminal punishment for rape, but then you go on to quote the Deuteronomy passage proving the contrary (*the man that lay with her shall die*). Keyword being *appear*, since after much unnecessary and easily avoidable headache, the reader is finally forced to conclude that what you *probably* meant to ask all along is how come that there is no capital punishment for the rape of an unwed woman *specifically*. (Though clearly not all readers, which would explain why this question is still closed as unclear).

Comment: Having arrived at this conclusion, however, the perplexed reader is then even further intrigued as to how you could have missed the rather obvious answer (Ezekiel 18:21-27, 33:9-19), which makes perfect sense in light of the perpetrator not being able to try and become a decent person by marrying an already married person. At which point his eyes fall on the highlighted portion of the aforementioned Deuteronomy quote, finally enabling him to understand that you apparently interpret it as saying that rape is as punishable as murder, which would then make perfect sense of your initial question.

Comment: But this only helps to provoke yet another (third) round of head-scratching, as to why on earth one would interpret that passage in such a manner in the first place, when all it means is that just as an attacked-and-killed person is not responsible for its own attack-and-murder, so is an attacked-and-raped woman not responsible for her own attack-and-rape, which fits beautifully with the three preceding sentences (*the man only that lay with her shall die, but unto the damsel thou shalt do nothing, for there is in her no sin worthy of death*).

Comment: @Lucian Thank you for such a detailed report. I rewrote the question to narrow it down. Plase note, that the verse in the Torah speaks of two sins in one - adultery AND rape, and the sinner is executed for the adultery part, not rape. In the case of unmarried grown-up woman, there's no punishment AFAIK.

Comment: @AlBerko: *the sinner is executed for the adultery part, not rape* - Were that the case, the text would be completely superfluous, since it would needlessly repeat a specific instance (adulterous rape) of an already presented situation (adultery in general). A more natural reading would be that the prescribed punishment is for adulterous rape specifically, but, for obvious reasons, a man cannot die twice (except perhaps for the two people resurrected by Elijah and Elisha).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, negative prohibitions carry a penalty of lashes. In this case, there is no punishment of lashes, because no prohibition has a penalty of both lashes and money (e.g. in [Makot 4b](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=25&daf=4b&format=pdf); as DoubleAA noted, there is one exception, which is slandering a virgin). Rambam mentions this in passing in [1:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=3925), in a case where there *are* lashes for a different prohibition (such as incest), and in such a case there is no fine (though he still must pay damages).

As to *why* he isn't lashed for this offense, I think that it's more usual to not be punished with lashes in commandments between people (rather than between people and God). Most cases (such as theft, damages, extortion) demand repayment rather than lashes. Only a few cases (murder, manslaughter) carry a heavier penalty (death and exile respectively). It does seem that the case of rape was associated more with the former case than with the latter.

(Note: I originally wrote that the reason was because the prohibition was attached to the positive commandment of marrying the woman. I changed it after some problems were pointed out with the answer.)

Comment: Does this also apply where the עשה it is connected to requires the consent of another person? In this case, he may only marry the woman if she agrees to marry him...

Comment: If the original wording was "One can not rape, but if he does he marries the victim" - that would be Nitak L'ese in my understanding. This phrasing is explicit about stealing -  והשיב את הגזילה, or לשם ישלם.

1. Rambam's prohibition of having relations without Kiddushin has no Ese.
2. The obligation to marry is only in place when she's under 12, is she's Bogeret (or many other cases), there's no obligation to marry whatsoever.

Comment: I reread some of the sources, and it seems that the reason is more connected to the fine (and not to being ניתק לעשה). I'll try to see if I can find this dealt with explicitly.

Comment: I also did some background checking, and it seems that a rape is no different than simply damaging one's fellow, which is עין תחת עין - get away with payments only. Rambam is clear that the rapist is paying all the damages, but sees no criminal part in it.               This is also true for a husband raping or otherwise damaging his wife.

Comment: @AlBerko _Rambam is clear that the rapist is paying all the damages, but sees no criminal part in it. This is also true for a husband raping or otherwise damaging his wife._ That comes back to the general question (addressed in Rishonim) of whether or not there is a prohibition to damage someone. I don't see any evidence from the above discussion, what Rambam holds about it.

Comment: @AlBerko paying nezek is ממון whereas an ones pays קנס. There are nafka minahs, such as needing semicha to rule on קנסות

Comment: @mevaqesh Maybe I am charged emotionally here and it impairs my judgement. If we take a rape of say a divorced grown-up woman,  it does not fall under קנס, damages aside (agreed), what happens? He transgressed Lav d'Orayso "לא תהיה קדשה" as in Rambam, why there's no criminal punishment?

Comment: @AlBerko As the post notes, its essentially the same as if I cut off your arms and legs. There is no "criminal punishment" officially determined. This is just one more example of that general phenomenon. No doubt a competent functioning government would choose their own mode of punishment. For a taama dikra approach to bein adam lahavero in general, (of which this is just a subset), consider asking separately, and make sure to indicate that when you ask why, you don't mean: "what are the relevant halakhic rules", but "why did God choose to set up the Torah this way".

Comment: I edited and clarified my question. For you I'd add an additional question: our sages had rules so many Takkonoys on Shabbos for example, how come they did not see to set a Takkono for a rapist? They could institute whatever punishment they wanted to להרחיק אדם מן העבירה. As we see from Gemora in Keddushin and Soyto and Kessubos, rape was very common back then.

Comment: @AlBerko Who says rape was common among Jews? (Remember to use a @ if you want a user to be pinged about your comment). If they had a problem in a particular place, the local government could have made a takkana. More than that is likely impossible to know. They probably didn't leave records of why they didn't make a particular takkana. What sort of takkana are you even envisioning? There is already a prohibition of yihud.